# How to improve where clause condition with unique of two columns combined?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables of User(id, name, ...) and friends(id, user_id, friend_id). I would like to check the relationship if users are already friends. But I feel like it could have done better. Please advise, thank you.

With the below function, I can already is ***user_a*** is a friend with ***user_b*** regarding who added who.

> 

```
public function isFriend($friend_id) {

    $isFriend = false;
    $isFriend = Friend::where('user_id', auth()->id())
                        ->where('friend_id', $friend_id)->exists();

    if(!$isFriend)
        $isFriend = Friend::where('friend_id', auth()->id())
                        ->where('user_id', $friend_id)->exists();

    return $isFriend;

}
```

Comment: the first `$isFriend = false;` is overwritten, so you can remove that line. You can use one query with `where()` and `orWhere()`

Comment: @GertB. thank you for your response. I just updated my code, what do you think?

Comment: A lot better since you only use one query. There are still other solutions if your db structure allows them, but this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I removed $isFriend = false; Here is my data:

| id | user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

```
public function hasFriendship($friend_id) {
    
    return Friend::where(function($query) use ($friend_id)
    {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('friend_id', $friend_id);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($friend_id)
    {
        $query->where('friend_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('user_id', $friend_id);
    })
    ->first();
}
```